# Selenium Remote Webdriver on Windows7 localhost throws null pointer exception

Tags: python, windows, selenium, remotewebdriver

I have been using RC successfully over the years.I have decided to switch over to Remote Webdriver to get all those new benefits.
First I wanted to try a basic scenario.
1. Open Google.com
2. Type "Selenium" in the search box.

I start Standalone server with the following command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar -port 4450
```

Then I execute my python test script which contains the lines below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=caps,command_executor='http://localhost:4450/wd/hub')
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id("gbqfb").send_keys("selenium")
driver.quit()
```

I can see that google.com opens but "selenium" is not typed in the search box. In the standalone server logs I get the exception below.

Configuration : Windows 7 Professional-32bit. Selenium-server-standalone-2.31 Python 2.7.3 Firefox 17.

I am wondering What I am missing here? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
C:\Users\engin\Downloads>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar -port 4
450
Nis 04, 2013 11:24:35 AM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
11:24:36.180 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 23.7-b01
11:24:36.180 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 x86
11:24:36.195 INFO - v2.31.0, with Core v2.31.0. Built from revision 1bd294d
11:24:36.351 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.
1:4450/wd/hub
11:24:36.367 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
11:24:36.367 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server
/driver]
11:24:36.367 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
11:24:36.367 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
11:24:36.398 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@b1656f

11:24:36.398 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
11:24:36.398 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4450
11:24:36.398 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@18facfb
11:25:42.012 INFO - Executing: [new session: {platform=ANY, javascriptEnabled=tr
ue, browserName=firefox, version=}] at URL: /session)
11:25:48.987 INFO - Done: /session
11:25:49.003 INFO - Executing: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.GetSess
ionCapabilities@19e774d at URL: /session/3ff2660f-0a08-420d-b3df-eb5b699e4a6b)
11:25:49.003 INFO - Done: /session/3ff2660f-0a08-420d-b3df-eb5b699e4a6b
11:25:49.018 INFO - Executing: [get: http://www.google.com] at URL: /session/3ff
2660f-0a08-420d-b3df-eb5b699e4a6b/url)
11:25:51.436 INFO - Done: /session/3ff2660f-0a08-420d-b3df-eb5b699e4a6b/url
11:25:56.444 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.id: gbqfb] at URL: /session/3ff
2660f-0a08-420d-b3df-eb5b699e4a6b/element)
11:25:56.537 INFO - Done: /session/3ff2660f-0a08-420d-b3df-eb5b699e4a6b/element
11:25:56.537 INFO - Executing: [send keys: null null, [s, e, l, e, n, i, u, m]]
at URL: /session/3ff2660f-0a08-420d-b3df-eb5b699e4a6b/element/0/value)
11:25:56.537 WARN - Exception thrown
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.SendKeys.call(SendKeys.java
:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.SendKeys.call(SendKeys.java
:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession
.java:169)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    11:25:56.553 WARN - Exception: null
```

Comment: Are you sure the locator "gbqfb" is for a text input and not any other element?

Comment: I am sure the locator is correct because if I deliberately provide an incorrect locator, I get NoSuchelementException : Unable to locate the element

Comment: See this line: `11:25:56.537 INFO - Executing: [send keys: null null, [s, e, l, e, n, i, u, m]]` - it seems that first two keys are null... but I do not have any idea how to fix it...

Comment: @AbhijeetVaikar also the type of the element is correct. I just tried it with Selenium IDE find feature.(id=gbqfq). It yellow higligths the search box. With this id I am still getting the null pointer exception. Also tried opening www.altavista.com and entering some text in the search box(id=yschsp) there ..no difference..

Answer (score 2):

One solution we have found was...
Adding -Duser.language=en to the java arguments while starting the server solved the issue!!
and by the way my OS language is Turkish(TR).

Answer (score 0):

I had a really similar issue before and I found this:

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/659

It seems like the method `send_keys` is broken. They should have fixed it already so you could pull the newest version and build it yourself or you can use an older version where the `send_keys` method works.

That worked for me.